# Apache griffin build error

Tags: apache-spark, griffin.mvccontrib

Hi I am trying to install apache griffin as per the Readme in the apache incubator-griffin git [page](https://github.com/apache/incubator-griffin).

I am almost through all the dependency installations and while doing a mvn installation one of the test fails with the following error.

> Failed tests:
>   SparkSubmitJobTest.test_setDataConnectorPartitions:142  Argument(s)
>   are different! Wanted: dataConnector.setConfig(
>       {partitions=date=20160409, hour=12} );
>   -> at org.apache.griffin.core.schedule.SparkSubmitJobTest.test_setDataConnectorPartitions(SparkSubmitJobTest.java:142)
>   Actual invocation has different arguments: dataConnector.setConfig(
>       {partitions=date=20160409, hour=09} );
>   -> at org.apache.griffin.core.schedule.SparkSubmitJob.setDataConnectorPartitions(SparkSubmitJob.java:167)

I can see in the code that it expects hour to be 12 but somehow its passing 9 instead. Searched online for a fix and but got close to no resource on griffin.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Can anybody help me with this please.

PS : sorry if the tags used are incorrect. Cant find an exact match for apache griffin and I don't have enough reputation to create new tag.